# PHP form writing a blank row in MySQL

Tags: php

My PHP form is writing a blank row in my MYSQL database.

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong? I am frustrated at this point. When I hit submit, it's creating the row within the database, but there is no data.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "blah";
$password = "blah2";
$database = "blah3";

$vdesc = $_POST['desc'];
$vproductname = $_POST['productname'];
$vproductver = $_POST['productver'];
$vtypeofhard = $_POST['typeofhard'];
$vosname = $_POST['osname'];
$vfreqofocc = $_POST['freqofocc'];
$vsolution = $_POST['solution'];

mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query = "INSERT INTO recordofbugs VALUES('','$vdesc','$vproductname','$vproductver',
'$vtypeofhard','$vosname','$vfreqofocc','$vsolution')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="buglistcss.css">
<title>Bug List</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Bug List</h1>
<?php $servername = "localhost";
$username = "blah";
$password = "blah1";
$database = "blah2";
mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM recordofbugs";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();?>
<div id="data">
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Description | </font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Product Name | </font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Product Version | </font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Type of Hardware | </font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Operating system | </font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Frequency of Occurence | </font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Proposed Solution</font>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
<?php $i=0;while ($i < $num) {$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"desc");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"productname");$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"productver");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"typeofhard");$f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"osname");$f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"freqofocc");$f7=mysql_result($result,$i,"solution");?>
<tr>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f5; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f6; ?></font>
</td>
<td>
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f7; ?></font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php $i++;}?>
</div>
<h1>New Bug Report</h1><br>
<form action="buglist.php" method="post">
<p>
(*)Bug Description: <input class="field" type="text" name="desc"><br>
(*)Product Name: <input class="field" type="text" name="productname"><br>
(*)Product Version: <input class="field" type="text" name="productver"><br>
Type of Hardware: <input class="field" type="text" name="typeofhard"><br>
Operating System: <input class="field" type="text" name="osname"><br>
Frequency of occurence: <input class="field" type="text" name="freqofocc"><br>
Proposed Solution: <input class="field" type="text" name="solution"><br><br>
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
</p>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. Please, avoid include your ENTIRE code in question. Put some snippet code where you think is the problem or its the real point of your question

Comment: That's a personal choice, I love seeing all the code, makes it much easier to fix.

Comment: Or not. could make more difficult to fix with a lot of code like this one.

Comment: If you find yourself posting random material to get past the low quality filter, it is usually the case that you've not written enough. Here, it would be good to see a description of the debugging you've done, and where you think the problem might be. (You have SQL injection problems too, which must be fixed before you go live).

Comment: Check if you are receiving the data in $_POST variable on the script. User filter_input to prevent SQL injection, and add some constrains on your table, to prevent empty rows.

Comment: Sorry I posted the whole block of code. I wasn't exactly sure where the problem was so I didn't want anyone wasting their time looking at code that wasn't at fault. I had nothing else to write in my post, I think what I had typed was plenty in all honesty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the first variable in your insert to be `null` instead of `''`, ie

```
"INSERT INTO recordofbugs VALUES(null,'$vdesc','$vproductname','$vproductver', '$vtypeofhard','$vosname','$vfreqofocc','$vsolution')"
```

I would also suggest you add your column names.

Anyway, I would output your query any verify the data is there.  I don't see anything in your script that would cause the data to be blank, but worth double checking.

Also make sure you don't have any mysql errors, but I would imagine if you are seeing errors you wouldn't being see a blank row.

Like I said I don't see anything majorly wrong that would result in the php script not seeing the submitted form data, but perhaps export your table schema so we can see what that looks like.  I'm thinking that is where the problem lies

Comment: Changing the first value to NULL seemed to do it! That's all I did and the data is showing up!  Thanks a ton!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get when I export into a csv file. (won't let me post the picture) and I've also got the structure of the database listed as well. thanks for all the responses!

;;"0";;;; multiple times where I tried entering data with my form.

1   desc    text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
2   productname text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
3   productver  int(11)         No  None
4   typeofhard  text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
5   osname  text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
6   freqofocc   text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
7   solution    text    latin1_swedish_ci

No  None

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump($_POST)` and check if all values are passed correctly. Then print `var_dump($query)` and if you have access to `phpMyAdmin` you can try sending this sql query manually and check the error returned.